# 英語が残っている: バッジ獲得の時刻表示の隣（Awarded）

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

以下、英語が残っています。
翻訳候補「Awarded -> 授与」

[image: 指摘用画像]

「このバッジを持っている他のユーザー」をクリックした先でも同じようにAwardedが残ってます。